# Slim restful webservice

Tags: cors, httpurlconnection, slim, postman

I have a simple restful webservice in slim which is hosted on byethost.

```js
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

require 'database.php';

use Slim\Slim;


//for cors
$corsOptions = array(
    "origin" => "*",
    "exposeHeaders" => array("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "X-authentication", "X-client"),
    "allowMethods" => array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS')
);

$app = new Slim();

$app->add(new \CorsSlim\CorsSlim($corsOptions));


//2 params
//first - device_id
//second - state
$app->get('/api/changestate','changeState');

//1 param
//param = value
$app->get('/api/changetemp','changeTemp');

$app->get('/api/openall','openAll');

$app->get('/api/closeall','closeAll');

$app->get('/api/getstate','getState');

$app->get('/api/gettemp','getTemp');




function changeState(){
    global $pdo;

    $app = Slim::getInstance();

    $deviceId = $app->request->params('device_id');

    //1-ON
    //0-OFF
    $state = $app->request->params('state');

    $sql  = 'UPDATE device SET state=? WHERE id=?';

    $perepareStatement  = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $perepareStatement->execute(array($state,$deviceId));

}

function changeTemp(){
    global $pdo;

    $app = Slim::getInstance();

    $value = $app->request->params('value');


    $sql = 'UPDATE sensor SET value=? WHERE id = 1';

    $perepareStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $perepareStatement->execute(array($value));

}

function openAll(){
    global $pdo;

    $sql = 'UPDATE device SET state=1';

    $perepareStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $perepareStatement->execute(array());
}

function closeAll(){
    global $pdo;

    $sql = 'UPDATE device SET state=0';

    $perepareStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $perepareStatement->execute(array());
}


function getState(){

    global $pdo;

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM device';

    $query = $pdo->query($sql);

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($result);

}


function getTemp(){

    global $pdo;

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sensor';

    $query = $pdo->query($sql);

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($result);


}

$app->run();



?>
```

When I access this webservice from the browser, it is working fine. But when I try to access from Postman rest client or in android using `Httpurlconnection` class, it gives me the following response :

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
            <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("4a187380bc9ff2b039ef2a8c5d6a5a12");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://homecontrol.byethost32.com/api/gettemp?ckattempt=1";
            </script>
            <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I thought the problem is something to do with CORS and I added `corsSlim` but no luck. I am pretty new to these technologies. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have to simulate the javascript behaviour using Postman/Android.

Comment: i want my rest api to be able to be connected by client(android/postman) without worrying about this "javascript thing".like connecting to public api such as twitter api which is straightforward.what do i need to do my rest api to get that kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is networking related. When accessing from the browser, probably you're using `localhost` or you've set the host address (like when using `/etc/hosts` file). But when you call the same URL from the Android device, you're accessing the IP/address from outside your network.

I'm supposing that because the response you're getting seems to be related to a home automation system. A temperature sensor to be more precise: http://homecontrol.byethost32.com/api/gettemp?ckattempt=1.